# How do I convert Json array into string in wcf?

Tags: json, string, wcf, visual-studio-2012

I have seen many ways to convert json array into string but none of them are working.

Can anyone help me how do I convert json array into string in wcf.

Please help me through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I using JSON.NET for serialize and deserialize objects. You can install it with nuget, http://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/

```
MyObject result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject >(jsonString);

string stringResult = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject);
```

Comment: Can u specify the code to deserialize object? @Daniel

Comment: Now instead of MyObject I have written dynamic and Suppose I got 
{"Tb_id":1,"detail": [{ "Item_id":"Bvrgs1" , "Quantity":1,"add_Details":"Spicy" },{ "Item_id":"Bvrgs2" , "Quantity":2,"add_Details":"Sweet" },{ "Item_id":"Bvrgs3" , 

"Quantity":3,"add_Details":"" }]} 

Now what do I do if I want Tb_id,Item_id,Quantity,Add_Details separately?